# Check the status of a Finder copy-paste operation from Apple Watch

Tags: finder, applications, apple-watch, copy-paste, watchos

Today I had to leave my Mac, while a copy-pasting operation was in progress with a large number of files. I found myself wanting to know how long the operation had left (and if it had encountered any issues, duplicates etc.). This left me wondering, would there be a way to view this progress on an Apple Watch?

I'm not entirely sure if this already exists via an app on the App Store (please let me know, if there's one) or if someone has coded a sideload app. Either way, let me know because I'd love to investigate. I understand how the app would encounter issues interacting with the actual macOS, but I wonder if anyone has any insight.

Perhaps if not for the Apple Watch, but for the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt such an app exists even for iOS, leave aside watchOS, for watching Finder file operation progress. This is a very specific use case and I am not certain if there are any official APIs that lets you obtain this data in a watchOS or iOS app.

A simple solution that I can think of is to install a VNC viewer app on your iPhone (many available on the App Store). Configure your Mac for screen sharing. Now using the viewer component on your iPhone/iPad, you can visually see the screen of your Mac and check file operation progress.

VNC apps are not just viewer and you can also control your Mac from your iPhone, thereby giving you the ability to perform operations on your Mac remotely.

Comment: I had a feeling there wouldn't be suitable APIs, but I also thought perhaps someone else has wanted to achieve the same thing and found other ways. I have used VNC before but I was hoping for a more slimline approach without all the "remote-access" features. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Perhaps finding a solution for remote-access on the Watch would have been a better question..